# Parar animação com requestAnimationFrame no canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Estou utilizando o `Canvas` para fazer isso https://jsfiddle.net/m42hu8zg/ , só que gostaria de parar a animação ao clicar na `div` usando alguma funcionalidade do `requestAnimationFrame`. Eu usei o `setInterval` mas a animação não fica legal, então resolvi usar o `requestAnimationFrame` mas nao sei parar a animação apos um click e continuar apos outro click.

O código funciona simplesmente com uma circunferência por cima de uma linha usando o método `clip()`, e quando clica na  `div`, a circunferência move no eixo x passando por cima da linha mostrando-a, só que quero parar a animação apos um click e depois continuar (como um botão de play e stop, dando a intenção que a linha parou de crescer).

Seria possível também eu definir um caminho para a circunferência percorrer apos o click ? Exemplo: http://prntscr.com/7y1wpw

*No meu exemplo ele segue um caminho, mas é em linha reta, eu queria que a circunferência move-se por um caminho já pre-definido como no exemplo acima.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, o que eu fiz foi simplesmente colocar:

```
ctx.clearRect(cx, 0, canvas.width, canvas.heigth)
```

Com `cx` movendo para esquerda ou para direita, dai ele dava impressão que a linha crescia ou diminuía!